# Java final anonymous class vs garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, final, anonymous-class

My question is about how should we use anonymous class when passed as parameter to async callback ?
For example if I have the following code :

```
interface MyListener {
    void onSucces(String requestedAction, JSONObject response);
    void onError(String requestedAction, JSONObject response, int statusCode);
};

interface CallbackInterface {
    void onResponse(String requestedAction, JSONObject response, int statusCode);
};

void doAsyncJob(String action, CallbackInterface callbackItf); 


void makeJob(String action, final MyListener listener) {
    doAsyncJob(action, new CallbackInterface {
        void onResponse(String requestedAction, JSONObject response, int statusCode) {
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                listener.onSucces(requestedAction, response);
            } else {
                listener.onError(requestedAction, response, statusCose);
            }
        }
    });
}


for(i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    makeJob("Action_" + i, new MyListener{
        void onSucces(String requestedAction, JSONObject response) {
            //process response
        }
        void onError(String requestedAction, JSONObject response, int statusCode) {
            //process error
        });
}
```

calling "makeJob" in a loop by allocating each time new listener (MyListener) that is used later by the 
"onResponse", this listener could become eligible for garbage collector ?
Is need to keep one reference to this listener to be sure that when used later in "onResponse"  is not already garbaged ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects become eligible for garbage collection when no other objects reference them.

In your case, the `MyListener` objects are passed down to makeJob, where they are then referenced by the `CallbackInterface` objects.  Note that the reference does not need to be a member variable explicitly declared within `CallbackInterface` (actually, the java runtime generates one and copies the reference).

So as long as the `CallbackInterface` object exists, its associated `MyListener` will not be garbage collected.  This means that as long as doAsyncJob keeps a reference to the `CallbackInterface` for as long as the job is running, then the `MyListener` will always be available.

Comment: This is available also for native object ? I mean if I have the code like this :

Comment: //native function C++
void nativeFunction(new NativeObject()) {
... do async job in native that use the "obj"
}

this obj when will be garbaged ?

Comment: So some Java method has invoked a native method, and is waiting for it to return.  That means that that java method is still in the JVM, which would still be maintaining state - including all the references, so MyListener is still safe.

Comment: For your native example in the above comment "new NativeObject()",  are you intending that to be Java's "new" or C++'s "new" operator?   If Java's, then that object will also be eligible for garbage collection as usual.  However, if you mean that "new" to be C++'s, then that's an entirely different question, and that object will NOT be garbage collected by Java;   you will have to ensure you delete it in your native code.